# software for server/network monitoring

Tags: monitoring, graph

Is there any good software people would recommend that I could just run on my extra monitors for live updating network/server status? Like graphs or stuff like that.

Just something that would look good, be useful, and put my extra monitors to use when they are not needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

SSH in and run htop. Very impressive for people walking by. Followed by any of the Matrix screensavers, but that isn't really very useful for monitoring the system.

Answer (score 1):

Nagios, muni, Cacti, mrtg, smokeping and countless others. Depends on what you want to monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Nagios is a good monitoring tool and the price is right (free) but you do have to provide the labor.

Comment: ya i have nagios, but I dont really find it too useful for something I would like... unless there are some plugins I dont know about

Comment: Care to be more specific on that?  Also this question has been asked numerous times on this site.  Search a bit.

Comment: Um...what do you like?